# Firebase Authenfication via signInWithEmailAndPassword() neither succeeds or fails

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I try to implement Firebase-authentification with Email and Password.

Here is the code I have written. I guess it syntactically correct.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

signIn.setOnClickListener {
    mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword("demo@gmx.de", "geheim")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this,
                OnCompleteListener<AuthResult?> { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) { // Notify user of failure
                        Log.i("onCreate", "OnComplete")
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
                    Log.i("onCreate", "OnFailure!")
    })
}
```

Neither of the two listener is ever executed. **What I'm doing wrong there?**

Respectively: **What might cause the issue?**

Comment: is `signIn` initialized properly?

Comment: @Ben Shmuel: Yep, definitely. If I attach a breakpoint to "mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword() ...", then it holds there. So, the setOnClickListener works. It's just that none of the addOn-listeners ever get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();   
        signIn.setOnClickListener {
            mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword("demo@gmx.de", "geheim")
              .addOnSuccessListener { Log.i("onCreate", "OnSuccess") }   <------- Use addOnSuccessListener instead
              .addOnFailureListener { Log.i("onCreate", "OnFailure!") } 
        }
```

> .addOnCompleteListener Returns true if the `Task is complete`; false otherwise. 
>   .addOnSuccessListener Returns true if the `Task has completed successfully`; false otherwise.
>
> A Task is "complete" when the work represented by the Task is
>   finished, regardless of its success or failure. There may or may not
>   have been an error, and you have to check for that.
>
> A Task is "successful" when the work represented by the task is
>   finished, as expected, with no errors.

if you want to do your way

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    signIn.setOnClickListener {
        mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword("demo@gmx.de", "geheim")
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                when {
                    it.isComplete -> { Log.i("onCreate", "isComplete") }
                    it.isSuccessful -> { Log.i("onCreate", "isSuccessful") }
                    it.isCanceled -> { Log.i("onCreate", "isCanceled") }
                    it.exception != null ->{Log.i("onCreate", it.exception.toString())}
                }                   
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.i("onCreate", e.toString())
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank a lot. But it all doesn't help. It stays the same: Neither the success- or the failure-handler are entered. No idea anymore ...

Comment: maybe it's already login Try to sign out first FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(), or uninstall the app and install again

Comment: Started from scratch again. Copied the code provided by Google for the setOnClickListener-body: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password  ... but it all didn't help.

Comment: Sorry. Haven't had access to the code during the work-week. Please see attached screenshot, which I have added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCompleteListener()` change if statement. Here the logic seems to be incorrect.
 You should use `if(task.isSuccessfull) { log.i("onCreate", "Successful")}` to log successful event.

Comment: @ Hamza Javed : Sorry. But I have checked the syntax. "task.isSuccessful" is correct. "isSuccesfull" leads to an unresolved reference-error.